# ER model design

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I have three tables: user, friend and family.
User  is entity.
Friend is relationship.
Family is relationship.

However, if I would like to set privacy level which can control who can view my full information. i.e. Only friend can see my hobbies, and only family can see my current location. 
I don't know how I can implement this on ER design.

Option 1:

```
User{ 
attribute 1: ID;
[other attributes]
}

Friend{
Attribute 1: FriendID;

}
Family{
Attribute 1: family ID;

}
```

How can I meet the requirements? Still confused about it. Anyone has a rational solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ER diagrams are really a seperate issue from security.  ER diagrams just state what exists and how it is realated.

The best place for this kind of secuiry is in the model.  When you someone asks for your current location, check if they are your family, etc...

This is especially true since current location is likely to be calculated from GPS, not stored as an entity in the database.  If it is, you could potentially include a forign key from current location to familyID that would tie these together.

If this doesn't make sense, please provide more details on hobbies and current location.

Comment: Yea. Maybe you are right. This can be done in coding stage. Setting flags would be the solution.

Comment: If I have to add these limitations into my ER model. Would there be viable way to make this happen? For example, add an extra field to family, named level. Set the level value be some integer, like 1 or 2. If so, the ER model would somehow lower programmer's load... However, it may be harder to manage because of the redundant data. Do you have any have-to-do solution for this problem?

Comment: Let me re-explain the problem. Table user which should contain usrID, name and some other attributes. User should be able to set privacy level of his/her information (i.e. which users can see his information. Assume that just friends marked as close or family are able to see the information). In this case how would I build the ER diagram?

Comment: OK. I see there are something better to be done in application level. And no need to bother this problem. Efficiency comes first. Thank you Vulcronos @Vulcronos